# Obter o nome do remote

Tags: git

No *bash* do Git, para atualizar o *branch* local em uso a partir de um *branch* remoto, nós usamos o comando:

```
git pull nomeDoRemote nomeDoBranch
```

Ainda no *bash*, ao se navegar para o diretório de um projeto, nós vemos algo mais ou menos assim:

```
usuario MINGW64 ~/foo/bar (nomeDoBranch)
```

Dessa forma, é fácil saber o nome de um *branch* para atualizá-lo - com a suposição de que tenha sido criado a partir de um remoto, ou que ao menos esteja publicado.

Mas como podemos obter o nome do(s) *remote(s)* associados ao projeto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilizando o comando [`git remote -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html), você verá os repositórios remotos configurados no seu projeto local:

```
marcelo@marcelo-X555LF:/var/www/html/projeto$ git remote -v
origin  https://marcelodeandrade@gitserver.org/repositorio/projeto.git (fetch)
origin  https://marcelodeandrade@gitserver.org/repositorio/projeto.git (push)
```

Com o [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) você verá os repositórios remotos associados aos commits:

```
From https://marcelodeandrade@gitserver.org/repositorio/projeto.git
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        HEAD
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/heads/dev
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/heads/feature#10915
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/heads/feature#12617
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/heads/feature#14391
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Ou você pode usar o comando *git remote show*:

```
$ git remote show
origin
```